# NHibernate unit of work in ASP.net MVC filter using AutoFac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, autofac

I am trying to create a unit of work per request using NHibernate and Transactions. I have a filter in MVC that is applied globally. It looks like the following.

```
public class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ISession _session;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Constructor does NOT get run per request. 
        _session = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>();
        _session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
        _session.BeginTransaction();

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception == null)
        {
            _session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            _session.Transaction.Rollback();
        }

        _session.Dispose();

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Note that I am using dependency resolver to get the service which means that it's called each request rather than the constructor which is cached, or so I'm led to believe.

Now my Autofac module looks like the following :

```
public class AutoFacModule
{
    public static IContainer Build()
    {
        return Build(new ContainerBuilder());
    }

    public static IContainer Build(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        // You can register controllers all at once using assembly scanning...
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

        builder.Register(x => NHibernateSetup.CreateSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InstancePerHttpRequest();

        //Build Registry. 
        var returnContainer = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(returnContainer));

        return returnContainer;
    }
}
```

So from this, I thought that I would get a new _session per HTTP Request. But this doesn't seem to be the case. If I stick a breakpoint in an MVC Action, and load a page, wait for it to hit the breakpoint, then fire up a new tab and load the same page, wait for it to hit the breakpoint and then let both go on. I get an error of :

```
Transaction not successfully started
```

When I try and commit. This I believe is because the first request has already committed the transaction. Which seems to be because both requests are sharing an ISession instead of it being unique per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The act of posting to StackOverflow suddenly makes things all make sense.

So for some reason, it has to do with registering filters globally. Because I was a bit lazy, I had done the following

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new TransactionAttribute());
}
```

So basically wrapping every request in a transaction. This doesn't seem to want to work when using the DependencyResolver. If I remove this, and add the attribute directly on a method, things start working.

As a site note, I also found a different way to inject properties without using constructor using Autofac : http://alexmg.com/filterattribute-property-injection-in-autofac-mvc-3-integration/ which seems to be the default way when dealing with filters under autofac.

Something about this approach irks me a little though as having a property public like that seems a little odd (Since it really shouldn't be set by ANYONE except in a constructor). But, it does make things able to be unit tested (Although I assume the dependency resolver way has ways to be unit testable too).

So for now, I'll place the attribute directly on the actions. But it probably needs to be looked into as things like logging/error handling that may require injection surely would be in the globalfilters collection?